# CURL: POST XML data to server [cmdline WINDOWS]

Tags: xml, bash, post, curl, cmd

I'm trying to post an XML to a REST API via CURL:

```
λ curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://localhost/vcardservice -d '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes'?><ns2:vCardRequestStore>
    <vcardRequestList> <vcardRequest></vcardRequest></vcardRequestList></ns2:vCardRequestStore>'
```

but is not working

```
Error:
    < was unexpected at this time.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: strange, this works for me as is on Ubuntu with curl 7.35.0. obviously I get a 404 page, but no error. So I'm guessing it's a problem with your `vcardservice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with escaped double qoutes inside the data payload

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" standalone=\"yes\"?> ...
```

Comment: thanks, to fix I had to add double quotes instead of single quotes and escape the quotes in the backslash